# Installed ubuntu 14.04 on external HDD, can't move it to another computer

Tags: boot, external-hdd

I have recently installed ubuntu on a 1TB external hard drive, without any special partitioning, I used the express partitioning setting in the installation. Everything worked just fine as I was able to boot from the external hard drive and use ubuntu, and when I unplugged the hard drive from the computer it couldn't boot of course.

The problem is, when I plug the hard drive to another computer, and I have tried 3 different computers, they won't boot from it even when I change the boot order correctly in the BIOS, or I get a "no operating system" error.

I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you !

Comment: Make sure GRUB, Ubuntu's bootloader is installed in the external hard drive, not the internal one where the installation was done. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/180023/can-i-install-grub-on-an-usb-and-make-it-a-rescue-disk for instructions.

Comment: @user68186 Thank you for your comment. I had a hard time following the instructions on that link. Could you please explain specifically how I can install grub on the external hard drive using another computer / live cd? That would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using "Something Else" option while re-installing ubuntu on the hard drive, (from a live CD or installation disk) and specifying the boot manager location to be sdX (the external hard drive itself).

I guess that by installing ubuntu with express partitioning settings the boot manager was either placed on the wrong disk or on one of the disk's partitions. (sdX1 for example.)

Answer (score 0):

for a generic question like yours you can simply reinstall grub on your HDD.

use a Ubuntu Live CD or USB, plug your hard drive and open a terminal. Mount the partition where you installed Ubuntu, for example, if the hard drive is on sdb:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

after that, do a simply reinstall grub on the MBR's hard drive:

```
sudo grub-install –root-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdb
```

Comment: So you mean to say that the bootloader for example should be installed in sdX (where x can be a,b,c or other letters) signifying the external hard drive instead of the partition inside the hard disk (sdX1, sdX2, sdX3... so on) ?? Am I correct in this reasoning?